# Unable to limit the selections of items to 2 in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my `React-hooks` I am unable to limit my selections of items to 2, below code is not validating at the moment. Would like to display a validation message "Maximum items has been selected". What could be the reason ?

https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-brown-n8ki4?file=/src/App.js:463-492

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import Multiselect from "multiselect-react-dropdown";

const options = [
  { key: "Apple", id: 1 },
  { key: "Bags", id: 2 },
  { key: "Coat", id: 3 },
  { key: "Drum", id: 4 }
];

const App = () => {
  const maxOptions = 2;
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState([]);
  const handleTypeSelect = (e) => {
    setSelectedOption(e);
  };

  const onNominate = () => {
    alert("hello");
    // ...
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="navbar-nav">
        <div className="leftNavItem"></div>
      </div>
      <h1>Maximum 2 selections</h1>
      <div className="nomineeSelectBox">
        <Multiselect
          onChange={handleTypeSelect}
          options={selectedOption.length === maxOptions ? [] : options}
          displayValue="key"
          showCheckbox={true}
          noOptionsMessage={() => {
            return selectedOption.length === maxOptions
              ? "You have reached the max options value"
              : "No options available";
          }}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="nominateButton">
        <input type="button" value="Next" onClick={onNominate} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some problems in your code to `Multiselect` works properly:

1. You need `onSelect` event of the `multiselect-react-dropdown` component not `onChange`.
2. `selectedOption.length === maxOptions ? []` should change to `selectedOption.length + 1 === maxOptions ? []`
3. For showing the correct message for the no options selected, you need to change `noOptionsMessage` to `emptyRecordMsg`

So, final result should be:

```
 <Multiselect
          onSelect={handleTypeSelect}
          onRemove={handleTypeRemove}
          // onChange={handleTypeSelect}
          options={selectedOption.length + 1 === maxOptions ? [] : options}
          displayValue="key"
          showCheckbox={true}
          emptyRecordMsg={"You have reached the max options value"}
        />
```

In addition you should change the `handleTypeSelect` to :

```
  const handleTypeSelect = (e) => {
    const copy = [...selectedOption];
    copy.push(e);
    setSelectedOption(copy);
  };
```

Also you need to handle the multiselect when a item removes with `onRemove` method:

```
  const handleTypeRemove = (e) => {
    const copy = [...selectedOption];
    let index = copy.indexOf(e);
    copy.splice(index, 1);
    setSelectedOption(copy);
  };
```

[image: Edit amazing-paper-mdw16]

Comment: Thank you, after maximum item selected I should be seeing a message ""You have reached the max options value"", but now it is showing No Options avaialble

Comment: @soccerway updated the code. Please investigate it again.

Comment: @MajidMohammadi and soccerway be careful with the selectedOption, if you log it you will see that it is accumulating the whole selection each time.

Comment: Is it possible to include email to the option list, now it has only name right...

Answer (score 1):

You are always setting only one option. So you have always one option selected. What you need to do is

```
 const handleTypeSelect = (e) => {
setSelectedOption(prevArr => [...prevArr, e]); };
```

Do it like this so you can pull the option selected before.

Comment: Tried still able to select more than two items. What is the prevArr object for ?

Comment: when you are setting the state you have access to the previous state. in your case you need to get previous state as well